# Use of fscanf with array

Tags: c, arrays, file, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
   {

    FILE *buildingsptr;
    int ptr2[8];


    buildingsptr=fopen("buildings.txt","r");

    fscanf(buildingsptr, "%d", &ptr2);
    printf("%d", ptr2);


getch();
return 0;
}
```

I have a bigger code and I found that this part causes the problem. The "buildings.txt" file has some integer numbers in it like 24 or 7, I just want to print first number of the text but this code is giving me a number like 2293296, I am new in coding, so I couldn't solve my problem, I'll be grateful if you help me. :)

Answer (score 1):

`ptr2` is an array. You want to fetch (and print) one of its elements

```
fscanf(buildingsptr, "%d", &ptr2[2]); // fetch into the element with index 2
printf("%d", ptr2[2]); // print the value of the element with index 2
```

But you really should check the return value of `fscanf()` (and previously `fopen()`) to make sure all went ok

```
if (fscanf(buildingsptr, "%d", &ptr2[2]) != 1) {
    // there was an error
} else {
    printf("%d", ptr2[2]);
}
```

Don't forget to `fclose()` the file handle too.

Comment: Thank you so much, I solved it. But I have another question if you have time to answer, I'll use malloc instead of array, I get those integer numbers from the .txt file, I send those numbers to a pointer which is implemented by malloc, then I want to access that part of memory which is allocated by malloc. I remember something that I can use the pointer which have the head adress of the memory part, as an array. For instance, `ptr2=(int*)malloc(a*sizeof(int))` ; then `fscanf(buildingsptr, "%d", ptr2)`; how can I print my numbers to the screen? I tried a "for" loop like ptr[i] and I failed.

Comment: print with `printf("%d\n", *ptr2);`

Comment: @user3648312 start off by not casting malloc: `ptr2 = malloc(a * sizeof *ptr2);` The cast is cruft from 30 years ago that people have been copy-pasting ever since without applying some brain.  Also, you access this array in the same way as the other one: `ptr2[n]` to access the `n`-th element, indexed from `0`.